# Is "fruit" used as a countable or uncountable noun?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I don't know if "fruit" works as a singular or a plural in these cases:
HOW MANY fruit(s) or HOW MUCH fruit do you eat a day?
Today I have had three fruit(s).

Answer (score 4):

Uncountable.

The plural "fruits" is occasionally used to mean "types of fruit". However in your case you should use

> How many pieces of fruit?

> I had three (pieces of fruit).

(although a more natural response might be to list them, since a grape is so different from a grapefruit)

Answer (score 4):

When the question

> *How much fruit do you eat in a day?*

is asked, although the noun *fruit* is uncountable in this context, it is idiomatic to use a countable noun when you respond (as James K has already touched upon)

> *I eat three pieces of fruit every day.*

The same applies to other uncountable nouns, such as *money*:

> Q: *How much money do you have?*
>
> A: *I have three dollars.*

Comment: Is it more natural then to say "These fruit are all rotten" or rather "This fruit is all rotten". Does the word "fruit" without a final /s/ agree with a verb in the plural or in the singular?

Comment: *This fruit is all rotten* is the standard idiom. The word "fruit" without the final /s/ agrees with the singular verb, as I have written. (You will never encounter the construction *These fruits are all rotten* although it does conform to standard usage.)

Comment: Note that these are examples of how to respond to a quantitative question about an uncountable noun (*fruit/money*), with a different, countable noun (*pieces/dollars*).